# kmatch: Check propensity scores and individuals who are matched

Tags: stata, exact-match, propensity-score-matching

I'm using `kmatch` in Stata. The reason why I use `kmatch` is to use the command `ematch` to match exactly on a specific variable in addition to the propensity score matching. Here is my code:

```
kmatch ps treatment age sex edu (outcome), ematch(level) comsup
```

I think `kmatch` is different from `pscore` and `psmatch2` in that propensity scores will not be automatically stored in the dataset. I wonder if there is a way to save these propensity scores and to check which individuals are included in the matched sample.

Comment: `kmatch` is from SSC. I have never used it but I guess from the help that the `pspredict()` options may be what you seek.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't find that in pspredict() tho

Comment: Unfortunately this question will not progress unless someone familiar with that command chimes in.  The program author is prolific but doesn't hang around here. He may respond to personal email.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the help file, `help kmatch`. Add `generate[(spec)]` as an option to store the propensity scores as `_KM_ps`. Other helpful matching results also have the `_KM_` prefix. `wgenerate[(spec)]` generates variables containing the ready-to-use matching weights. `idgenerate[(prefix)]` generates variables containing the IDs (observations numbers) of the matched controls.

Here is an example.

```
webuse cattaneo2, clear 
kmatch ps mbsmoke mmarried mage fbaby medu (bweight), ///
generate(kpscore) wgenerate(_matched) idgenerate(_controlid) ate
```

Try this to compare results from `kmatch` and `teffects psmatch`, keeping only the propensity scores from each.

```
webuse cattaneo2, clear 
tempfile temp1 temp2 
keep mbsmoke mmarried mage fbaby medu bweight
gen id = _n
save temp1, replace

teffects psmatch (bweight) (mbsmoke mmarried mage fbaby medu), ///
ate generate(_pscore)
predict te_pscore, ps 
keep te_pscore id
replace te_pscore = 1 - te_pscore
save temp2, replace

use temp1
kmatch ps mbsmoke mmarried mage fbaby medu (bweight), generate(kpscore) ate 
rename _KM_ps k_pscore 
keep k_pscore id 
save temp3, replace

merge 1:1 id using temp2
drop _merge
list in 1/10

     +---------------------------+
     | id    k_pscore   te_psc~e |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |  1   .13229635   .1322963 |
  2. |  2    .4204439   .4204439 |
  3. |  3   .22490795   .2249079 |
  4. |  4   .16333027   .1633303 |
  5. |  5   .11024706   .1102471 |
     |---------------------------|
  6. |  6   .25395923   .2539592 |
  7. |  7   .16283038   .1628304 |
  8. |  8   .10881813   .1088181 |
  9. |  9   .10988829   .1098883 |
 10. | 10   .11608692   .1160869 |
     +---------------------------+
```